# DC Power Connector Type

Tags: power-supply, connector, charger, plug

I have looked at many DC connector types but still couldn't find what type is the following connector. It's not XLR or Power DIN. Any ideas?
It's similar to GX16-4 4-Pin 16mm Aviation Pug but it's not the same

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite certain it's from the [Hirose HR-30 series](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/HR30?lang=en#). 
You should measure the dimensions to confirm.

Comment: Proper coding would be HR30-7P-4S but I think HR30-7P-10S will do if you just leave 6 sockets unused. It's a proprietary Yamaha e-bike charger socket which is based on HR30.